# text near search bar magento ce 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, menu, navigation

I'm new to Magento and I would like to know how I can add a text next to the Search bar in Magento.

The search bar is placed in the right of navigation menu

Here's what I've tried :

1) created a text to be displayed in topmenu.html but appeared either in front or next to the menu but not next to the search bar

2)Created a static block and set the identifier and store view accordingly which resulted in the block appearing near the banner of the page.

3) Added to the existing static blocks in cms , which resulted near the cart button

4) Tried changing in header.phtml, page.phtml

5) used template links to find the path but couldn't exactly find it.

finally I've added the text in form.mini.phtml in catalog search, which i know isn't the best way to do.

The text appears below the search bar, and not to the right of it.

I've tried changing it in scss but it has no effect on it. Not even the font size changes. Cleared the cache too.

I'm a complete beginner so I'm not used to it. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 2):

- Go to
  `/app/design/frontend/YOUR_PACKAGE/YOUR_THEME/template/catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml`
- If it's not present, go to `/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml`
- Add code after 
  `<label>..</label>
  <input>...</input>
  <button>...</button>`
- Like this, `<label for="search"><?php echo $this->__('YOUR TEXT') ?></label>`

Comment: Thank you. I have added it before. The issue was that the changes were not detected. Solved it after starting compass watch.